# ViewState value not being retained during postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I make this piece of code work? I am dealing with a bigger issue but if I can make this work then I will know what to do.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        Response.Write(ViewState["Value"].ToString());
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewState["Value"] = "Button clicked";
}
```

Comment: you need to set Button1 enableviewstate property to true.

Comment: Best advice is to not use view state, it's horrible.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by putting my logic in pageLoad method in the page_PreRender method like this:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        Response.Write(ViewState["Value"].ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Page_Load event happens before Button1_Click and hence you wont be able to access a value that is not already set. 
You will need to use an event that happens after Button1_Click like Page_PreRender as you have used in the answer.

Please go through [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) to understand Page Life Cycle, which is invaluable in Asp.Net Webforms development.